# jQuery hover doesn't animate but has delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I have a problem with jQuery or jQuery UI. I want to animate a button on hover, but instead of animating it smoothly, it waits for specified time and then pops the change instantly. Any suggestions?

When I zoom in in Chrome, it seems the change is a two-step process. Maybe because it isn't much of a change, so it processes it that way?

```
$(".btn-form").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate(
            {
                borderWidth : "2px",
                borderColor : "#B27332"
            }, 500);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate(
            {
                borderWidth : "1px",
                borderColor : "gray"
            }, 500);
        });
```

Comment: can you provide html and css for this.

Comment: See the animation happens smoothly if you **[see a demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/87mzwh0w/)** where I've animated the `width` too. The problem would be the attributes you have chosen to animate and the values you have given to them.. Since they are very minute you cannot actually see them working properly.. **[See this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/87mzwh0w/1/)** where value for `borderWidth` is being increased..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works! Unfortunately, changes to the border from 1px to 2px in a smooth manner are not perceivable.

You can also try obtaining the same result using CSS-transition.

```
.btn-form {
border: 1px solid gray;
transition: border 500ms;
}

.btn-form:hover {
border: 2px solid #B27332;
}
```